# Internal Pyomo implementation error: "sympy expression type 'im' not found in the operator map"

Tags: sympy, pyomo

```
DeveloperError: Internal Pyomo implementation error:  
    "sympy expression type 'im' not found in the operator map"  
    Please report this to the Pyomo Developers.
```

Comment: Did you do what the message says, i.e., did you report this to the developers? What did they say? Are you asking us to fix some error in some package?

Comment: I reported this problem to the pyomo developer waiting for their feedback.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?